# rclone android (Termux) error: "Fatal error: failed to mount fuse fs: fusermount: signal: bad system call"

Tags: mount, android, error-handling, cloud, rclone

I'm in the middle of trying to mount my OneDrive cloud files to my android phone via Termux v0.118.0. I've been able to install rclone and link my remote drive to the phone, where I can confirm commands like `rclone lsd remote:` work and list all my directories in my remote's root location. I'm currently trying to mount my drive as a network disk to my phone as detailed [here via rclone's website](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/). Along the way, I've installed the `libfuse2` package for more FUSE capability. Unfortunately, when running `rclone mount remote:/folder/to/be/mounted/ ~/local/mounts/name/`, I'm prompted with the error:

```
2022/01/30 14:34:20 Fatal error: failed to mount fuse fs: fusermount: signal: bad system call
```

I've tried seeing if `sudo` would circumvent this, however, since my device is not rooted, any usage of `sudo` returns

```
No superuser binary detected.
Are you rooted?
```

My ultimate goal here is to be able to run a few python scripts from my OneDrive folder that will update certain `.csv` files and a `.pkl` file. If this can be done without needed to use `rclone mount`, I'd be open to an alternative solution.

EDIT: I was able to get something to work functionally using `rclone` commands `sync` and `copy`. Ultimately, I have something that works but I'm still curious as to why I'm not able to do this via the `mount` method. Answers that address this appropriately will be accepted.

Comment: I have same problem